# Disable/lock Keyboard Permanently

Tags: vb.net

I new to vb.net. I try to create system to disable/lock keyboard.
And also i try many code from google but its all work only in that form. I want It disable/lock permanently.

```
Public Class Form1 
    Private Declare Function BlockInput Lib "user32" Alias "BlockInput" (ByVal fBlock As Integer) As Integer
```

Private Declare Function ShowCursor Lib "user32" (ByVal lShow As Long) As Long

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
    BlockInput(1) 
    ShowCursor(0) 
End Sub 

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click 
    BlockInput(0) 
    ShowCursor(1) 
End Sub 

 End Class
```

Thanks.

Comment: _its all work only in that form_ > means what ?? be specific in your requirement and post the code

Comment: Did you try anything before asking?

Comment: Yes.Below is my code.

Public Class Form1
    Private Declare Function BlockInput Lib "user32" Alias "BlockInput" (ByVal fBlock As Integer) As Integer
    Private Declare Function ShowCursor Lib "user32" (ByVal lShow As Long) As Long
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        BlockInput(1)
        ShowCursor(0)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        BlockInput(0)
        ShowCursor(1)
    End Sub
End Class

Answer (score 0):

Try this but this will block the mouse and the keyboard so i would put an timer to re-enable it

```
Public Class Form1 
    Private Declare Function BlockInput Lib "user32" (ByVal fBlock As Long) As Long 
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
        Timer1.Interval = 5000 '5 seconds
        Timer1.Enabled = True 
        BlockInput(True)
    End Sub 

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick  
        Timer1.Enabled = False 
        BlockInput(False) 
        MsgBox("You can now use your mouse and keyboard")
    End Sub
End Class
```